# Use progress bar to show the progress of doing a function?

Tags: vb.net

I had a small VB project and got a problem that needs your helps.

In the project in VS 2008, I had **a button** named **"demo_btn"**, **a progress bar** named **"complete_pb"**,  **a function** named **"doSomething"** and **a class** like this:

```
Public Class Demo
    Private Sub demo_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles demo_btn.Click

        'the progress bar starts running when the button is clicked
        doSomething
        'the progress bar stops at 100% when the function doSomething is done

    End Sub
End Class
```

All I need is that the progress bar starts running when the button is clicked and it stops at 100% when the function **doSomething** is done. The problem is that I dunno when the function **doSomething** finishes.

I've googled it but I couldn't find anything that works for me.

You guys have any ideas to help me?
thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, you do know when it finishes because the control returns from `doSomething` back in to `demo_btn_Click`. That is unless you are using another thread somewhere.

Comment: Check the [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) about BackgroundWorker

Comment: A `ProgressBar` is not magic.  All it does is display a visual representation of a ratio and it's up to you to provide that ratio.  You can only display progress if you can measure progress.  Can you measure the progress of `doSomething`?  If not the you can't display its progress.  that would be magic.  If you can measure it then do so and configure the `ProgressBar` appropriately.  Otherwise, the best you can do is to set the `Style` to `Marquee` to indicate that something is happening.  Even then, you'll need to do that something on a secondary thread or the `ProgressBar` can't animate.

Comment: @Martheen, I think ideas about [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) works for me :)